# Problema al acceder a IP dentro de la misma red

Tags: python, reactjs, api, flask, net

Tengo dos servicios corriendo en la computadora A:

- API en 192.168.1.15:5000
- Frontend en 192.168.1.15:3000

Desde la misma computadora A puedo acceder sin problemas, ya sea con la ip, con http://localhost:port y con http://0.0.0.0:port. Sin embargo, desde una computadora B, conectada a la misma red de la computadora A no puedo acceder hacer consultas a la API pero sí acceder al Frontend.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Puede ser una infinidad de cosas y faltan antecedentes, partiendo por quien rechaza la conexión (el stack TCP/IP o la API).

Comment: Puede PING computadora A desde computadora B?  Puede ser firewall tambien.

Comment: @Duston Sí, el PING desde la computadora B hacia la A y viceversa se ejecuta correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Como pones que usas flask, intuyo que estás en modo debug y por eso no puedes acceder desde otro PC que no sea el local.

Pero como dice Candid Moe pueden ser muchas cosas distintas. Faltan datos.

Pero apostaría que tienes run(Debug=True) prueba run(host='0.0.0.0')

Comment: Esta es mi configuración:

class DevelopConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    PORT = 5000
    ENV = 'dev'
    HOST = '0.0.0.0'

Comment: si tiene el código en github con gusto le echo un vistazo y si a mi me funciona descartamos que sea problema del código, y nos centramos en problemas en la red.